# What does こと refer to in だけのことはある

Tags: grammar, formal-nouns

I'm trying to figure out what "こと” is referring to in this idiom/grammar point.

In the following example sentence:

彼は若いころから日本に住んでいただけのことはあって、さすが日本語がうまいんだね。

What does koto refer to here?

Additionally, is this perfectly interchangeable with だけあって

Compare the following 2 sentences

彼は若いころから日本に住んでいた**だけのことはあって**、さすが日本語がうまいんだね。
彼は若いころから日本に住んでいた**だけあって**、さすが日本語がうまいんだね。

Are these different? If so, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shouldn't this phrase using 【だけのこと】 mean "just for that"?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1945/shouldnt-this-phrase-using-mean-just-for-that)

Comment: ＠sawa That question was incredibly helpful in understanding the overall meaning (especially the "だけ" aspect) however I couldn't seem to find any good reason as to why こと has been thrown haphazardly into the mix. I tried to differentiate this question by focusing on こと and contrasting between both だけのことはあって and だけあって.

Comment: I see. That may make a point.

Comment: Also possibly related: [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-in-sentences-such-as)

Answer (score 4):

I think `こと` just refers to the general situation, and does not refer to some particular thing. A close English analogue may be `the case` as in `It is the case that he was living in Japan`. Your two sentences with and without `こと` are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't refer to anything. Again, it's just two grammar points:

- だけのことはある is surely because ～; not surprising that ～; It was worth ～
- だけあって because, as expected (used for positive things)

Examples:

> 毎日訓練してるだけあって上達した。

As expected after a while of daily training, he improved a lot.

> さすがにばかと呼ばれるだけのことはある。

He's not called an idiot for no reason indeed !

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful of an explanation "they're grammar points" is... I'm sure there is an explanation for this expression aside from tautology.

Comment: Well, I mean that there is no use in trying to do a fine grain analysis of each word, considering the meaning comes from taking groups of words.  A bit like wondering what "far" is to understand the difference between "as I understand it" and "as far as I understand it".  Also, it's a tautology for you *know* that they are two points, but it seems to me that phirru did not.