# what does だけに mean in this?

Tags: grammar

Looking for some help seeing whether I have understood the usage of だけに in the below. To summarise the conversation 御園 is saying that she was jealous of 佳奈. As she was explaining why she was jealous she became embarrassed and tried to change what she was going to say part way through, leading to the eventual ツッコミ by the narrator as the three of them spent most of the day eating out yesterday.

御園 says 音楽科だけに. Is this just to emphasise why she is jealous?(she specialises in music). edit: Thinking about it I'm not sure that makes sense. I originally thought she was saying that 佳奈 went to 河井楽器 but now I'm thinking she might be saying that she went there.

> 「正直言うと、ちょっと佳奈が羨ましかったんです」
>
> 「アホなところが？」
>
> 「違います」
>
> 「佳奈すけ佳奈すけって言われて、かわいがっ……」
>
> 勢いこんで言って、そこで止まった。
>
> 御園の耳たぶが赤く染まる。
>
> 「河井楽器に昨日行ったんです。音楽科**だけに**」
>
> きりっとした顔で言った。
>
> 一緒に飯食ってただろうが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ～だけに means "precisely because of ～". She said she went to 河合楽器 (shop name) and it must be natural because she was in the music department.

See also:

- [Meaning of "だけに"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54611/5010)
- [The meaning of なだけに in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74887/5010)
- [JGram - だけに](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=dakeni)

Comment: Not something like "I went to Kawai Instruments. The music section, as you would expect" ?

Comment: @kandyman Do you mean a certain section in the store called Kawai Instruments? Then, no, 音楽科 refers to a department of a school.

Comment: Ah I see. The fact that she belongs to the music department makes it a natural expectation that it was that shop she went to.