# What does というだけのこと mean here?

Tags: grammar, particle-だけ

I'm reading a novel and this line came up.

> 幸いにして今は虐められていないが､ それは､ クラスに私よりも虐められている子がいてくれるから**というだけのこと**｡

The context is that the narrator used to be bullied in class, but now that a new student has become the class's target of bullying.

What does **というだけのこと** mean in the above sentence?

Could the **だけのこと** be a shortened version of **だけのことはある** that is talked about in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1956/48610) answer? If that is correct , would the addition of **というだけのこと** be adding a nuance of "at least I can say this new student being bullied had the benefit of me no longer being bullied"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, だけのこと is not a contraction of だけのことはある. If anything, it is a contraction of だけのこと**だ**.

As explained on [this site](https://mainichi-nonbiri.com/grammar/n2-dakenokotoda/), it basically means *just*. In particular, the usage in the sentence is emphasis: *It is **just** because there is another who's bullied more than I*.

Note:

- The *benefit* implication comes from (いて)くれる. In this case it implies that the existence of 'the more bullied' benefits the speaker.
- The linked site has a separate entry for [だけのことはある](https://mainichi-nonbiri.com/grammar/n2-dakenokotohaaru/).